# Writing multi-line formula to range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Desired result in the formula bar:

```
=IF(True,
1,0)
```

These return generic 1004 error:

```vb
Selection.Formula = "=IF(True," & vbCrLf & "1,0)"
Selection.Formula = "=IF(True," & vbNewLine & "1,0)"
```

<s>`Selection.Formula = "=IF(True," & CHAR(10) & "1,0)"`</s> *(edited as Chr(10) does actually work, thanks Tim)*

Is there any possible workaround to get a new line in the formula bar?

Comment: Close with the 3rd one - `Chr(10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the formula bar supports only LF character, but it is possible:

```vb
selection.formula = "=IF(True," & vbLf & "1,0)"
```

As Tim pointed out in a comment above, this also works:

```vb
selection.formula = "=IF(True," & Chr(10) & "1,0)"
```